# Getting more than one image URLs from Twitter API search

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am making a twitter scraper using the official twitter API and want to extract image URLs for a given hashtag. Here is what I tried but this keeps returning only a single Image URL.

```
max_tweets = 90

search_results = api.search(q="tuberculosis filter:images", count=max_tweets, include_entities=True)
tweet_image_url = []
for tweet in search_results:
    if 'media' in tweet.entities:
        for image in  tweet.entities['media']:
            tweet_image_url.append(image['media_url'])
        
tweet_image_url
```